# Se puede formatear con ESCALA DE COLORES tablas HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html5, html-tabla

busque por la web pero no encontré, así que mi duda es si hay algún método ya hecho o forma de poder dar color de fondo a las celdas de una Tabla HTML dependiendo de su valor, por ejemplo en PORCENTAJES, que vayan los colores de X grupo de celdas en degradé dependiendo el numero de 0 a 100?  Como en las hojas de calculo de Google.

Pero me refiero a los formatos condicionales con escalas de colores como hay en Excel o Google Spreadshetts, es decir configurando solo el valor MINIMO y MAXIMO y que el formato de todo un conjunto de celdas se vea entre el rango de esos colores.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer la siguiente función y mandarla a llamar cada vez que requieras dar color, por ejemplo, cuando agregues una nueva celda:

```
function color(celda)
{
    var porcentaje = celda.innerHTML; //me imagino que será por el valor que contenga
    if(porcentaje == "100")
       celda.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; //aquí va el color que quieras
}   
function dar_color(){
    var celdas = document.querySelectorAll("td"); //puedes cambiar el selector css para que aplique sólo a ciertas celdas
    celdas.forEach(color);  

}
```

Comment: Hola @Luis Barajas, gracias ante nada por responder y Bienvenido!

Comment: Me refería a si se puede hacer como en este ejemplo con Google Spreadsheets https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mAb8krvWrAiOs_o9QKEqX8_c5BgnxvfTzbFPlQfM8Hc/edit#gid=0. Es decir definir solo 2 colores MAX y MIN y el resto se ajuste automaticamente.